# Rails: Combining last name and first name in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

FINAL SOLUTION:

I have a Rails 3 app that uses Devise to handle authentication. In the signup form i have the following fields:

```
  <p><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :last_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %></p>
```

I need to capitalize first and last names and combine them in the User model in a database field called 'login' (e.g. Lastname, Firstname). Here is the complete user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :login

  validates :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :presence => true

  before_create :create_login

  def create_login
    self.login = "#{last_name.capitalize}, #{first_name.capitalize}"
  end

end
```

Thanks.

Comment: syntax for concatenating string should be: self.login = "#{last_name},  #{first_name}"

Comment: tks @a3uge and @JeffPaquette. the error i keep getting is "undefined method `capitalize' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Don't forget those of us with double-barrel surnames. Mine is Burn-Murdoch not Burn-murdoch. Same applies to O'Leary, McDonald, etc.

Comment: Hey, @Colin. If there is a simple solution to this, can you let me know. At this point i can't devote the time to writing a long solution to address this. Thank for the thought. I'll make a note to come back to this later in the development of this app.

Comment: No simple solution really. Personally I'd assume that the user has entered their names in the case as they should be written, and not transform them at all. I guess it would be reasonable to catch names that are all lowercase, and then use capitalise on them. That would turn "mcdonald" into "Mcdonald" but would leave "McDonald" alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I genuinely, honestly, and truly applaud your use of the power of Ruby, but since this is such a straightforward and static concatenation of two strings, I'd go with:

```
def create_login
    login = "#{last_name.capitalize}, #{first_name.capitalize}"
end
```

As for the `nil:NilClass` issue, are you adding first_name and last_name columns to your users table in your associated migration?

Comment: thanks. rake db:migration produced first_name and last_name columns in the database. Validation results in "First name can't be blank" and "Last name can't be blank". It is interesting that the fields created outside the stock Devise model are the ones that won't pass validation.

Comment: thks @mharper. i added a separate post solely devoted to the validation issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806048/devise-additional-columns-to-user-model-not-validating

Answer (score 1):

```
before_create :create_login
validates :first_name, :presence => true
validates :last_name, :presence => true

def create_login
  login = [last_name, first_name].map(&:capitalize).join(", ")
end
```

Short explanation

I think it is good to get `first_name` and `last_name` on registration: so we will ad validation to it. Also it is good idea to validate length and match it with some regexp.

Then, as far as login is creates only once, we will add `before_create` callback, which will be executed only when object is creating (not updating). `before_create` callback will be run only if validation is passed, so if `first_name` or `last_name` is blank - validation won't be passed and callback won't be executed till `first_name` and `last_name` is filled.

**UPD**

Ok, as far as you get your error:

```
def create_login
  login = [last_name, first_name].compact.map(&:capitalize).join(", ")
end
```

Comment: Thanks @fl00r. last.name should be last_name? i am getting the following error: undefined method `capitalize' for nil:NilClass

Comment: tks again @fl00r. still getting undefined method `capitalize' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @fl00r the whole model is shown above. i commented out the validation because i get "Attribute names must be symbols". I figured one problem at a time. With no validation, i still get "undefined method `capitalize' for nil:NilClass".

Comment: add validation in another way (separate for each attribute - answer is updated). For `undef method capitalized...` use `compact` method: `login = [last_name, first_name].compact.map(&:capitalize).join(", ")`

Comment: @fl00r i changed the validation so it is not an array and now it works. For some reason, first and last names are coming back as blank.

Comment: you should add them to `attr_accessible`: `attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :login, :first_name, :last_name`